# Lagrangian of a piezoelectric material

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, continuum-mechanics, piezoelectric

I am confused about the Lagrangian of a piezoelectric material. I have seen multiple sources that seem to contradict each other.

The way I personally approach the problem is the following:

$$L = K - U\,, $$

where $K$ is the kinetic energy, and $U$ is the potential energy which consists of mechanical strain energy $U_m$ + electrical energy $U_e$. I am ignoring the work done by external forces and charges for now since they are not relevant to the discussion.

We have the following:

\begin{align}
K = \int\frac{1}{2}\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i dV\, ,\\
U_m = \int\frac{1}{2}S_{i}T_{i} dV\, ,\\
U_e = \int\frac{1}{2}E_{i}D_{i} dV\, ,\\
\end{align}

where $\rho$ is the density, $\dot u_i$ is the velocity, $S_i$ is the strain tensor (Voigt notation), $T_i$ is the stress tensor (Voigt notation), $E_i$ is the electric field, $D_i$ is the electric displacement field. This results in the Lagrangian:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}\int\left(\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i - S_{i}T_{i} - E_{i}D_{i}\right) dV\, .$$

The problem is that most references write the Lagrangian as:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}\int\left(\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i - S_{i}T_{i} + E_{i}D_{i}\right) dV\, ,$$

with the sign in front of the electrical energy reversed. Examples:

- [Example 1](https://scmero.ulb.ac.be/Publications/Thesis/Piefort01.pdf): if you go to page 56, you'll see they derive the Lagrangian from the electrical enthalpy, and I don't get why it gives a different result (in the form of a + sign in front of the electrical energy).
- [Example 2](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=lCePDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&dq=piezoelectric%20%22lagrangian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqwp3bzN3oAhUBxYUKHVooDGQQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=piezoelectric%20%22lagrangian%22&f=true): same result, with the constitutive relations substituted in the Lagrangian.

So my question is twofold:

1. Where is the error in my approach in that it yields the wrong sign in front of the electrical energy?
2. In the main book I'm studying, which is *Engineering Analysis of Smart Material Systems.* Donald J. Leo, 2007, if you go to [page 218](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=jGAvKfLykNsC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=The%20tilde%20over%20a%20symbol%20denotes%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20strain%20and%20electric%20displacement%20are%20expressed%20in%20terms%20of%20the%20local%20piezoelectric%20coordinates%20and%20not%20the%20global%20coordinates.%20The%20local%20coordinate%20system%20for%20each%20piezoelectric%20element%20can%20be%20transformed%20to%20the%20global%20coordinates%20through%20the%20transformations&source=bl&ots=5tyv1NmGD0&sig=ACfU3U2coUWoCyy1dRJ25BpxoEszouMnTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQhc_02t7oAhVs8-AKHf4rAXMQ6AEwAHoECAsQKA#v=onepage&q=The%20tilde%20over%20a%20symbol%20denotes%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20strain%20and%20electric%20displacement%20are%20expressed%20in%20terms%20of%20the%20local%20piezoelectric%20coordinates%20and%20not%20the%20global%20coordinates.%20The%20local%20coordinate%20system%20for%20each%20piezoelectric%20element%20can%20be%20transformed%20to%20the%20global%20coordinates%20through%20the%20transformations&f=false), equation 5.47, the author gives the potential energy of a piezoelectric material (static case, no kinetic energy so $L=-U$):

$$U = \int\left(\frac{1}{2}S_{i}c_{ij}^D S_{j} - S_ih_{ij}D_j + \frac{1}{2}D_{i}\beta_{ij}^SD_{j}\right) dV\, ,$$

which is actually derivable from *my Lagrangian approach* rather than the one given in the two previous reference examples when you substitute the constitutive relations into the Lagrangian:

\begin{align}
T_i = c_{ij}^DS_j - h_{ij}D_j\, ,\\
E_i = - h_{ji}S_j + \beta_{ij}^S D_j\, .
\end{align}

So which Lagrangian is the correct one (which sign in front of the electrical energy is correct) and how can we reconcile the contradictory references?